# How to mock a tornado coroutine function using mock framework for unit testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, tornado

The title simply described my problem. I would like to mock "_func_inner_1" with specific return value. Thanks for any advises :)

code under test:

```
from tornado.gen import coroutine, Return
from tornado.testing import gen_test
from tornado.testing import AsyncTestCase

import mock

@coroutine
def _func_inner_1():
    raise Return(1)

@coroutine
def _func_under_test_1():
    temp = yield _func_inner_1()
    raise Return(temp + 1)
```

But, this intuitive solution not work

```
class Test123(AsyncTestCase):

    @gen_test
    @mock.patch(__name__ + '._func_inner_1')
    def test_1(self, mock_func_inner_1):
        mock_func_inner_1.side_effect = Return(9)
        result_1 = yield _func_inner_1()
        print 'result_1', result_1
        result = yield _func_under_test_1()
        self.assertEqual(10, result, result)
```

With below error, seems _func_inner_1 is not patched due to it's coroutine nature

```
AssertionError: 2
```

if I add coroutine to patch returned mock function

```
@gen_test
@mock.patch(__name__ + '._func_inner_1')
def test_1(self, mock_func_inner_1):
    mock_func_inner_1.side_effect = Return(9)
    mock_func_inner_1 = coroutine(mock_func_inner_1)
    result_1 = yield _func_inner_1()
    print 'result_1', result_1
    result = yield _func_under_test_1()
    self.assertEqual(10, result, result)
```

the error becomes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tornado/testing.py", line 118, in __call__
    result = self.orig_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "tornado/testing.py", line 494, in post_coroutine
    timeout=timeout)
  File "tornado/ioloop.py", line 418, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
  File "tornado/concurrent.py", line 109, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "tornado/gen.py", line 175, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "coroutine_unit_test.py", line 39, in test_1
    mock_func_inner_1 = coroutine(mock_func_inner_1)
  File "tornado/gen.py", line 140, in coroutine
    return _make_coroutine_wrapper(func, replace_callback=True)
  File "tornado/gen.py", line 150, in _make_coroutine_wrapper
    @functools.wraps(func)
  File "functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
  File "mock.py", line 660, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __name__
```

This is the closest solution I can find, but the mocking function will NOT be reset after test case execution, unlike what patch does

```
@gen_test
def test_4(self):
    global _func_inner_1
    mock_func_inner_1 = mock.create_autospec(_func_inner_1)
    mock_func_inner_1.side_effect = Return(100)
    mock_func_inner_1 = coroutine(mock_func_inner_1)
    _func_inner_1 = mock_func_inner_1
    result = yield _func_under_test_1()
    self.assertEqual(101, result, result)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two issues here:

First is the interaction between `@mock.patch` and `@gen_test`.  gen_test works by converting a generator into a "normal" function; mock.patch only works on normal functions (as far as the decorator can tell, the generator returns as soon as it reaches the first `yield`, so mock.patch undoes all its work). To avoid this problem, you can either reorder the decorators (always put `@mock.patch` *before* `@gen_test`, or use the `with` form of `mock.patch` instead of the decorator form.

Second, coroutines should never raise an exception. Instead, they return a `Future` which will contain a result or an exception. The special `Return` exception is encapsulated by the coroutine system; you would never raise it from a Future. When you create your mocks, you must create the appropriate Future and set it as the return value instead of using side_effect to raise on exception.

The complete solution is:

```
from tornado.concurrent import Future
from tornado.gen import coroutine, Return
from tornado.testing import gen_test
from tornado.testing import AsyncTestCase

import mock

@coroutine
def _func_inner_1():
    raise Return(1)

@coroutine
def _func_under_test_1():
    temp = yield _func_inner_1()
    raise Return(temp + 1)

class Test123(AsyncTestCase):

    @mock.patch(__name__ + '._func_inner_1')
    @gen_test
    def test_1(self, mock_func_inner_1):
        future_1 = Future()
        future_1.set_result(9)
        mock_func_inner_1.return_value = future_1
        result_1 = yield _func_inner_1()
        print 'result_1', result_1
        result = yield _func_under_test_1()
        self.assertEqual(10, result, result)

import unittest
unittest.main()
```