# Raise exception or return gen.Return object in Tornado coroutine

Tags: python, tornado

We have a Python 2 project where we actively use coroutines. We can't find any guidelines on exceptions handling inside coroutines.

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836577/how-to-mock-a-tornado-coroutine-function-using-mock-framework-for-unit-testing/27880772#27880772) lead developer of Tornado mentioned that `coroutines should never raise an exception`, but it is not clear why. Looks like this approach works and heavily used in Tornado.web itself:

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/blog/blog.py#L180

```
class AuthCreateHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("create_author.html")

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        if self.any_author_exists():
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(400, "author already created")
        hashed_password = yield executor.submit(
            bcrypt.hashpw, tornado.escape.utf8(self.get_argument("password")),
            bcrypt.gensalt())
```

**tornado.web.HTTPError** just extends base **Exception** class. Also, discussion here https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/759#issuecomment-91817197 suggests that raising exception inside coroutine is appropriate.

Also [here](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/), active Tornado contributor suggests that raising exceptions is fine:

```
class PostHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, slug):
        post = yield db.posts.find_one({'slug': slug})
        if not post:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404)

        self.render('post.html', post=post)
```

Is there any downsides to raising exceptions inside Tornado coroutines or should we `raise gen.Return(exception_object)` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 2, only use `raise gen.Return(value)` to return a normal value, not to raise an exception. It is exactly the equivalent of `return value` in a coroutine in Python 3.

To raise an exception from a coroutine, a normal `raise Exception()` is correct. The wonderful thing about coroutines is their exception-handling semantics are pretty much the same as regular functions.

Answer (score 4):

Raising exceptions inside coroutines is perfectly normal. When I said "coroutines should never raise an exception" I was referring to what happens when you *call* a coroutine without `yield` or `await`: The exception is captured and held until the coroutine's return value is either `yielded` or `awaited`.